# Number of combinations of digits where consecutive identical digits cannot be inverted to produce a new combination

Tags: combinatorics

I have a number in base $10$ containing $N$ digits of $1$, and $1$ or more digits that are $1$-digit prime numbers. The prime number digits can be repeated.

For example, $111225777$.

I wish to know how many "combinations" (not in the usual mathematical sense) of the digits of this number exist for which consecutive identical digits do not form a new "combination". In other words, the order of the indices of $2$ digits matter only if the digits are different. For example, $2235$ has the 1st digit and the 2nd digit equal to $2$, a counted combination is $2325$ but just by inverting the first and the second digit you do not create a counted combination.

**Update:** Another example:

The matching combinations of the digits $K1111$ are

1. $K1111$
2. $1K111$
3. $11K11$
4. $111K1$
5. $1111K$

In total here are 5 possibilities, not $2^5$.

Comment: Usually , $1$ is not considered to be a prime number.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you wish to count how many $N$-digit numbers can be formed with the digits $1, 2, 3, 5, 7$ if the order in which the digits appear does not matter.  Please confirm or clarify.

Comment: The order in which the digits appear does matter, but only for different digits. It is just like, if I have the array {2, 2, 3, 5} in which the first 2 has the index 1 and the second 2 has the index 2, inverting them will not count as another "combination", but if I permute the indices array and obtain {2, 3, 2, 5}, then this counts as another "combination".

Comment: In that case, there are five choices ($1, 2, 3, 5, 7$) for each of the $N$ positions, so there are $5^N$ possible sequences.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I updated the question with a new example, for which your formula is not functioning well.

Comment: You chose a particular example.  The reason there are five arrangements in the second example is that there are five ways to place the $K$.  The number of possible arrangements of the digits $111225777$ is $\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{3}$ since we must choose three of the nine positions for the $1$s, two of the remaining six positions for the $2$s, one of the remaining four positions for the $5$, and all three of the remaining positions for the $7$s.  However, when you consider all possible sequences of length $N$ formed with the digits $1, 2, 3, 5, 7$, there are $5^N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be two different questions here:

> How many sequences of length $N$ can be formed using the digits $1, 2, 3, 5, 7$ with repetition?

There are five choices for each of the $N$ positions in the sequence, so there are $5^N$ such sequences.

This type of problem is called a [permutation with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_with_repetition).

> How many distinguishable sequences of length $N$ can be formed with $n_1$ $1$s, $n_2$ $2$s, $n_3$ $3$s, $n_5$ $5$s, and $n_7$ $7$s, where $n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_5 + n_7 = N$?

Let's consider the following example:

In how many distinguishable ways can the elements of the sequence $1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7$ be arranged?

There are a total of $1 + 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 18$ numbers in the sequence.  We can fill one of the eighteen positions with the $1$ in $\binom{18}{1}$ ways, two of the remaining seventeen positions with the two $2$s in $\binom{17}{2}$ ways, three of the remaining fifteen positions with the three $3$s in $\binom{15}{3}$ ways, five of the remaining twelve positions with the five $5$s in $\binom{12}{5}$ ways, and all of the  remaining seven positions with the seven $7$s in $\binom{7}{7}$ ways.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{18}{1}\binom{17}{2}\binom{15}{3}\binom{12}{5}\binom{7}{7} = \frac{18!}{1!17!} \cdot \frac{17!}{2!15!} \cdot \frac{15!}{3!12!} \cdot \frac{12!}{5!7!}  \cdot \frac{7!}{7!0!} = \frac{18!}{1!2!3!5!7!}$$
such arrangements.  The factors of $1!$, $2!$, $3!$, $5!$, $7!$ in the denominator represent, respectively, the number of ways the $1$s, $2$s, $3$s, $5$s, and $7$s can be permuted among themselves within a given arrangement without producing an arrangement that is distinguishable from the given arrangement.

By similar reasoning, the number of distinguishable arrangements of a sequence of length $N$ with $n_1$ $1$s, $n_2$ $2$s, $n_3$ $3$s, $n_5$ $5$s, and $n_7$ $7$s, where $n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_5 + n_5 + n_7 = N$ is 
$$\binom{N}{n_1}\binom{N - n_1}{n_2}\binom{N - n_1 - n_2}{n_3}\binom{N - n_1 - n_2 - n_3}{n_5}\binom{N - n_1 - n_2 - n_3 - n_5}{n_7} = \frac{N!}{n_1!n_2!n_3!n_5!n_7!}$$

This type of problem is called a [permutation of a multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets).